# How to call the Delegate from viewcontroller to tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I'm having TableView as my MainView and viewcontroller as my Second view. The view controller has 3 textfields..I'm writing protocol so that I can get the values of Textfileds and can add into array of Tableview. The purpose is Whatever I give it in the textfield must get added in to the Table cell.
I'm having secondviewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<secondviewcontrollerDelegate> delegate;

 @protocol secondviewcontrollerDelegate<NSObject>
- (void)additemsintoarray;
@end
```

secondviewcontroller.m

```
-(IBAction)ok:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate additemsintoarray];
}
```

In Tableview.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController<secondviewcontrollerDelegate>
```

in tableview.m

```
- (void)additemsintoarray
{
    [self.array1 insertObject:scontroller.iditem1.text atIndex:[array1 count]];
    [self.array1 insertObject:scontroller.nameitem1.text atIndex:[array1 count]];
    [self.array1 insertObject:scontroller.iditem1.text atIndex:[array1 count]];
    [[self navigationController]popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note: the array is declared in Tableview with some values....
I'm getting an Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIView additemsintoarray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Let's see where you set the delegate.  (Also, can you format your code?  It's very difficult to follow in plain text.)

Comment: I set the Delegate in SecondViewController(ie. my Viewcontroller)

Comment: Whatever you're setting as a delegate is either a `UIView` instead of the object you think it is **or** your delegate object has been released and its memory re-used for a `UIView`.  Please show the code where the delegate is being set.

Comment: i cant get u.. i connected the delegete to the IB of UIVIEW

Comment: i used the above codes .. I did not do anything apart from that using delegates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RootViewController` should be the delegate. You have this issue because of an UIView is connected as a delegate of your `SecondViewController`.

Hope this helps

Comment: how to set the delegate of secondviewcontroller to the Rootviewcontroller

Comment: sorry Im new to the Delegate Concept.. Can u please help me?

Comment: how do i need to set the delegate to acheive the result?

Comment: In your RootViewController, if you have a reference to your SecondViewController (call it _secondVC for example). Simply set your SecondViewController as follow : _secondVC.delegate = self;

Comment: I Tried this previously but put the code in wrong place.. You cleared it.. U simply Rocking!!!! Keep Doing:-)